# How to get the top card of a trello list

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, trello

I want to get the top card of a certain trello list and then have it post the cards name in my discord channel, however, I’m unsure how to get the very first card.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look at [Trello Rest API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/api-introduction/)

More precise pages for your need :

- [Get Lists on a Board](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/#api-boards-id-lists-get)
- [Get a Card](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/#api-cards-id-get)

Trello gives Node.js example on these pages.

After some research, this is how I manage to get the first card of a list that I found on a certain board by it's name :

```js
// Getting all lists from a certain board.
fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{id}/lists?key={apiKey}&token={token}`, {
    method: 'GET',
}).then(response => {

    let lists = JSON.parse(response.body);
    // Searching for a list with a certain name and store it's id.
    let certainListId = lists.find(list => list.name === "listName").id;

    // Use the stored id in certainListId to get all cards of the list.
    fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/lists/${certainListId}/cards`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => {

        let certainListCards = JSON.parse(response.body);
        // Cards in the array is in top to bottom order. So top one is the very first.
        let firstCard = certainListCards[0];

        // Send with the bot the name of the first (top) card thanks to firstCard.name property.

    }).catch(err => console.error(err));

}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I know most of the trello api and I’ve used it before, however, I’m unsure how to search for a card in a certain position.

Comment: I've edit my answer with a code example of requests towards Trello API to get first card of a list 